# ReactJS: Uncaught TypeError: this.props.updateCommentText is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a newbie and just followed a React tutorial on YouTube but I failed to click save button as well as edit button because of the same error (in the save and edit function) as the question title. I tried to ask the YouTube author, but still no respond.

This is the source code:

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {editing: false};
  },
  edit: function(){
    this.setState({editing: true});
  },
  remove: function(){
    this.props.deleteFromBoard(this.props.index);
  },
  save: function(){
    this.props.updateCommentText(this.refs.newText.value, this.props.index);
    this.setState({editing: false});
  },

  renderNormal: function(){
    return(
      <div className = "commentContainer">
        <div className = "commentText">{this.props.children}</div>
        <button onClick = {this.edit} className = "btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
        <button onClick = {this.remove} className = "btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
      </div>
    );
  },

  renderForm: function(){
    return(
      <div className = "commentContainer">
        <textarea ref = "newText" defaultValue = {this.props.children}></textarea>
        <button onClick = {this.save} className = "btn btn-success">Save</button>
      </div>
    );
  },

  render: function(){
    if(this.state.editing){
      return this.renderForm();
    }
    else{
      return this.renderNormal();
    }
  }
});

var Board = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return{
      comments: [
        "Hello",
        "Hola"
      ]
    }
  },

  removeComment: function(i){
    var arr = this.state.comments;
    arr.splice(i, 1);
    this.setState({comments: arr});
  },

  updateComment: function(newText, i){
    var arr = this.state.comments;
    arr[i] = newText;
    this.setState({comments: arr});
  },

  eachComment: function(text, i){
            return (
              <Comment key = {i} index = {i} updateCommentText = {this.updateComment} deleteFromBoard = {this.removeComment}>
                {text}
              </Comment>
            );
  },

  render: function(){
    return(
      <div className = "board">
        {
          this.state.comments.map(function(text, i){
            return (
              <Comment key = {i}>{text}</Comment>
            );
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Board />
  ,document.getElementById("target"));
```

Comment: You are not passing `updateCommentText` to `Comment`:  `<Comment key = {i}>{text}</Comment>`. Hence when `Comment` tries to call that prop as a function, you get an error. Solution: Pass all the props that the component requires.

Comment: I recommend that you check the date of that video. It seems old (few months is old in React world). React.createClass is deprecated. If you are a newbie, I recommend that you follow https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html and Joe Maddalone's https://egghead.io/courses/start-using-react-to-build-web-applications

Comment: Thank you guys for the suggestions, I just fixed it by following the solution of the guy below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `eachComment` in your render method loop.

```
render: function(){
    return(
      <div className = "board">
        {
          this.state.comments.map( this.eachComment.bind(this) ); //you may or not need the .bind() here
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I really appreciate it. Now I can edit comment, save it as well as remove it, but when I refresh the page, the old comments are still there. Do you have any solution in this case?

Comment: If you are storing changes in a database and requesting that data each time the component mounts, then you should see the updated data when you refresh the page. Where are you saving/retrieving data from and where in your code are you making the request for that data?

Comment: I am using Codepen, is that possible to update data there after reloading the page?

Comment: ?? You're writing this in Codepen? No, your data won't persist because you're not saving it anywhere. You're storing it in local memory and when you refresh the page, the memory gets wiped.

Comment: Alright, I got your point. I just try to program something like edit comments on Facebook then the comments save forever, so I tried Codepen to do this. Do you know any similar examples/source codes to this case? Thank you so much for your replies :)